# back up services on centos and restor it on another clean centos

Tags: service, centos, backup, config, centos6.5

i'm going straight to question..
is there any way to backup services configured on a Centos without system file of centos?
for example I want to back up OpenVP-n config and then restore it to another clean centos and just changing a few files..
or even back up a full Direct admin config and then restore it in another clean centos OS?
i don't want back up the whole centos..just i want backup configs on it..
I search out about this alot..but i didn't find anything working..please share your experience about this..
Is this even possible?
any help...?